# How to load test Kafka topics using Jmeter

Tags: apache-kafka, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to do the Load/Performance Test of Kafka Topics using Jmeter.
Scenarios:
Request to Kafka Read Response from Kafka
Request to Kafka Read Response from other MQ
Request to other MQ read response from Kafka

Could anyone help with how we can achieve this, any setup or anything?

Answer (score 2):

1. To send message to Kafka:

   - [PepperBoxKafkaSampler](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#pepperboxkafkasampler)
   - or [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), you will have to write some Groovy code, check out [Kafka Producer in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-producer-in-java) and [KafkaProducer class JavaDoc](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)
2. To read message from Kafka:

   - [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)  - you will have to write some Groovy code, check out [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter/) and [Writing a Kafka Consumer in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/writing-a-kafka-consumer-in-java)

Comment: It is really a nice way to do so.